# How can I pass raw XML data to a MediaWiki template?

Tags: xml, mediawiki

This is how you can display source code in MediaWiki:

```
<syntaxhighlight lang="xml" line>
    <abc x="123" />
</syntaxhighlight>
```

In this example "`<abc x="123"/>`" will be rendered properly. But what if I would like to pass this XML snipplet "`<abc x="123"/>`" to some arbitrary template which *in turn* will pass this content to the `syntaxhighlight` extension? How can this be done? Standard approaches do not seem to work.

---

What I've figured out already:

- The `syntaxhighlight` extension can be invoked via `{{#tag:syntaxhighlight{{{1}}}|lang="xml"|line=1}}`. This can be put into a template.
- Passing some arbitrary XML content to the template seems to be the problem. Whatever I try does not seem to work. Even using `<nowiki>...</nowiki>` does not help: In that case all "`<`" get replaced by "`&lt;`".

Do you have any ideas or even know a solution to this problem?

---

Update: I did a fresh installation of MW 1.34.3 in order to have it as identical as possible to people trying to help me here on stackoverflow. Now:

- MW: 1.34.3
- SMW: 3.2.0
- SyntaxHighlight: 2.0

The template named `SVGExample`:

```
{{#tag:syntaxhighlight|{{{1|}}}|lang="xml"|line=1}}
```

The contents of the wiki page:

```
{{SVGExample|<nowiki><abc x="123"/></nowiki>}}
```

Result:

```
1   &lt;abc x="123"/&gt;
```

It does not seem to be a matter of MediaWiki extensions. I deactivated all extensions except `MagicNoCache`, `SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi`, `ParserFunctions` and I got the same result.

---

Update for those that want to dive deeper into this:

It seems that resolving the placeholders introduces the problem here. Even with the suggested way of passing data to arguments there is some processing: Comments are filtered out. And my experiments in custom extensions indicate that as soon as you resolve the arguments passed to the template the data gets HTML encoded thus resulting in unwanted `&lt;` entities (and other entities). The SyntaxHighlight extension does some kind of magic to avoid this phenomenon as it receives the raw data after resolving the template arguments where a classic approach with `$parser->recursiveTagParse(...)` fails in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a template, say, `Template:Xml`:

```
<includeonly>{{#tag:syntaxhighlight|{{{1|}}}|lang="xml"|line=1}}</includeonly>
```

Invoke this template like this: `{{xml|1=<abc x="123" />}}`. Note `|1=`.

Alternatively, create `Template:=` as `=` and invoke `{{xml|<abc x{{=}}"123" />}}`, escaping each equal sign: `=` → `{{=}}`.

The equal signs in anonymous parametres of parser functions need escaping, so that MediaWiki does not take it for a separator between parametre name and value.

Therefore, another alternative is to declare `Template:xml` with a named parametre, as follows:

```
<includeonly>{{#tag:syntaxhighlight|{{{xml|}}}|lang="xml"|line=1}}</includeonly>
```

and call it like this: `{{xml|xml=<abc x="123" />}}`.

Comment: Thank you for your response but that was exactly what I tried and what did not work. The result is "`&lt;abc x="123" /&gt;`" and not a "`<abc x="123">`".

Comment: Strange. It worked on my wiki. Is your wiki public? If not, what is your MediaWiki and SyntaxHighlight GeSHi version? Alsom are you talking about HTML source or how it looks in the browser?

Comment: It's a 1.33.0 using SyntaxHighlight version 2.0.

Comment: I just checked. It also doesn't work with a second wiki being of version 1.34.1.

Comment: Mine MW is newer: 1.34.3. Are other languages displayed correctly? Have you run `composer install --no-dev` / `composer update --no-dev` in the extension directory? Have you run the two scripts in the `maintenance` subdirectory?

Comment: The release notes do not state any change to this parsing/data passing mechanism. I just looked into that right now. I will therefore now follow your advice and install the 1.34.3 Wiki. Please stay tuned, I'll give feedback soon.

Comment: I'm 99 % sure this sneeds to work. There is no way that it can display escaped xml. What if you subst the template? `{{subst:xml|1=foo}}` should display what the template inserted, which in turn may indicate where the error is easily.

Comment: Typical MW dependency hell. (I never saw software worse than MW in that regard.) Result: Wasted 3 hours. I update my question providing more details.

Comment: @Regis May, sorry that I was not clear but I never advised you to upgrade; two minor versions would make no difference. What I recommend, provided you invoke the template exactly as I wrote, is to check whether SyntaxHighlight highlights other languages and run `composer update` and maintenance scripts for this extensions.

Comment: I repeat: call the template like this:`{{SVGExample|1=<abc x="123"/>}}`. It's important.